# How to play the next song in tableview automatically when first song finish

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, xcode7

I put songs into a table, and i want when frist song finish play next song in table view .. >>

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {


    if  let audio=NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource( elmp3[indexPath.row] , ofType: "mp3")
    {
        let url=NSURL (fileURLWithPath: audio)

        do {


            player = try AVAudioPlayer (contentsOfURL: url)

        }

        catch{"erorr"}
```

When you press in cel song play in the same view

This is the Array songs

```
var elmp3 = ["001","002","003","004","005","006","007","008","009","010","011","012","013","014","015","016","017","018","019","020","021","022","023","024","025","026","027","028","029"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an instance variable for *selectedIndex*.
2. Update the *selectedIndex* as indexPath.row in *didSelectRowAtIndexpath:* method.
3. Implement *AVAudioPlayerDelegate* methods and set delegate for **AVAudioPlayer** instance.
4. And in *audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:* callback method, increment selectedIndex and play next audio in list.

Below are the steps:

1.

```
var selectedIndex:Int = 0
```

2.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

//Set selected index
self.selectedIndex = indexPath.row

//get audio file URL at index
if  let audio=NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource( elmp3[self.selectedIndex] , ofType: "mp3")
{
    let url=NSURL (fileURLWithPath: audio)

    do {


        player = try AVAudioPlayer (contentsOfURL: url)
        //Set delegate for AVAudioPlayer
        player.delegate = self

    }

    catch{"error"}

 }
```

3.

```
class AudioPlayerController:UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate{

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(_ player: AVAudioPlayer,
                         successfully flag: Bool){

if flag == true && self.selectedIndex < elmp3.count{

//Increment current index
++ self.selectedIndex
 //Load audio at current index and play
 if  let audio=NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource( elmp3[self.selectedIndex] , ofType: "mp3")
{
    let url=NSURL (fileURLWithPath: audio)

    do {
        player = try AVAudioPlayer (contentsOfURL: url)
        player.delegate = self

    }

    catch{"error"}


}
}
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand exactly Can you explain more .. please

Comment: You need to handle AVAudioPlayerDelegate method _audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:_. In that method, increment your current index. And play audio  for current index. For ex. if initial value of currentIndex -> 0, after _audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying_, increment currentIndex->1. And play elmp3[currentIndex].

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but I can not use it also  :(